# Sending VF Email in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, vf-email-template

I'm trying to send one VF email template through apex.
while sending emails from Apex, my data is not rendering in the email template, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

**VF Email:**

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Follow-up Pending" recipientType="User" relatedToType="User">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <c:followUpComponent optyOwnerId="{!relatedTo.Id}" />
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

**Followup Component:**

```
<apex:component controller="FollowUpController" access="global">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  
  <apex:attribute name="optyOwnerId" assignTo="{!opptyOwnerId}"  type="Id" description="Opportunity Owner Id" />
  
  <html>
      <body>
          
          <p> Hi, </p>
          
          <p> Below are the Escalated Opportunities </p>
          
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <th> Opportunity Number </th>
                  <th> Escalation Level </th>
                  
              </tr>
              
              <apex:repeat var="pt" value="{!escalatedOppty}">
                       <tr>
                           <td> <apex:outPutText value="{!pt.Name}"/></td>
                           <td> <apex:outputtext value="{!pt.escalation_level__c}"/></td>
                       </tr>
              </apex:repeat>  
          </table>
          
      </body>
  </html>
  
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:component>
```

**FollowUpController:**

```
public class FollowUpController {

    public Id opptyOwnerId {get;set;}
    
    public List<Opportunity__c> getEscalatedOppty(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name, escalation_level__c FROM Opportunity__c WHERE escalation_level__c IN ('Level-1','Level-2') AND OwnerId =: opptyOwnerId];
    }  
      
}
```

Execute Anonymous Code for sending Email:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'test@gmail.com'}; 
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            mail.setTargetObjectId('0052v00000g1qkuAAA'); 
            //Change with Template ID
            mail.setTemplateId('00XBl000000VbZZMA0'); 
            
            mail.setBccSender(false); 
            mail.setUseSignature(false); 
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Test'); 
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 

Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Not sure what I'm missing, this email template is working when I click on Send Test and Verify Merge Fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<c:followUpComponent optyOwnerId="{!relatedTo.Id}" />
```

Should probably be:

```
<c:followUpComponent optyOwnerId="{!recipient.Id}" />
```

I'm not entirely sure why it should be inconsistent between the UI and Apex, but I have a feeling this should solve the problem.